# What is the file path to an iCloud Drive file?

Tags: macos, shortcuts-app

Imagine I have a file in `iCloud Drive/Sounds/Foo.mp3`. I want to play it via the `Play sound` action in the Shortcuts app.

I need to use `Get File`. When I use `Get File` I can choose the `iCloud Drive` service, but then if I want to hardcode the sound file to play, it asks me to manually enter in the path starting with `/Shortcuts/`.

I tried entering `/Shortcuts/Sounds/Foo.mp3` and `/Shortcuts/Sounds/Foo`, but both said:

> ## The file doesn't exist.
>
> The file "Foo" couldn't be opened because there is no such file.

How do I specify a path to a file in iCloud Drive in the Shortcuts app?

Comment: Are you sure about the paths starting with / ?

Comment: @nohillside I think he is talking about iOS.

Comment: @amdyes The question is tagged "macos".

Answer (score 6):

From [an OSXDaily article](https://osxdaily.com/2017/11/16/access-icloud-drive-command-line-mac/), "How to Access iCloud Drive from Command Line in Mac OS," from 2017, the answer appears to be  `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/`.

Checked it just now and this works for me as of December 2021.

I know I will forget this, so will make a symlink to it from my home directory!

Comment: For convenience you can create a symbolic link anywhere you like, e.g.: "ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs ~/iCloudDrive"

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Files app, you'll notice that there is a folder located at the root of your iCloud Drive called `Shortcuts`. You must move your file from `/Sounds/Foo.mp3` to `/Shortcuts/Sounds/Foo.mp3`, it appears that the Shortcuts app cannot read files that aren't located inside the `/Shortcuts/` folder.

Comment: This is a helpful answer to the original questioner, but it isn't responsive to the question that was asked, which is about pathnames of files in iCloud.