# Download file from iCloud/GoogleDrive from Terminal or script

Tags: terminal, icloud, finder, script

I use Ventura with iCloud and also GoogleDrive.
I have some files in iCloud, not physically available on my MacBook, but I could right-click on it and click to "download now" (basically OS downloads the file from iCloud or GoogleDrive making it available)

How I can perform this action from the Terminal? Or using a script.

I have some mp3 files in iCloud, and before Updating to Ventura 13.2, if I "launch" that file from Music Player it automatically downloaded the file and played it.

Now I'm forced to find the file in Finder and download It manually.

How Can I solve that?

Thank you very much

Comment: Get the link from iCloud (or whatever) and use `wget <link>` or `curl -O <link>`.

Comment: The problem is exactly this . What is the link??? It is a file inside my file system linked to cloud. Thanks

Comment: See this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/377423/119271  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?